# Python: Reading csv file from relative path does not work in Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have few csv files in a folder which is present in the same folder where my program is stored. I am using following code to read the csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
files = os.listdir('../review_data')

for file in files:
   os.chdir('../review_data')
   temp = pd.read_csv('../review_data/'+file,header=None)
   print(temp)
```

However, when I ran the above code, the print statement prints nothing. When I ran the same code (with some modification in file path ) in windows it works fine. However, it did not work in MAC. Could anyone help me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: what is the path relative to, the file?

Comment: @Manakin my relative path is /Users/Username/review_data

Comment: that's your issue most likely, the script is being launched from your terminal which is in directory `x` its expecting it to be in directory `y` try this `from pathlib import Path; csv_file = Path('/Users/Username/review_data').parent.parent.glob('*.csv')` then pass  each item into a read csv statement